# Concatenate IDs only IF not unique in table

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift

I am bit stuck in writing a query that might be easy for some of you. I am working with Redshift in Coginiti. So this is the problem I want to solve:
I have a a big table but for this particular query I will only use 3 columns: ID, X,Y
the requirement is if ID is unique then I should leave it as is, ID. If ID is not unique then I want to concatenate ID,X,Y. I am not looking to overwrite the column but rather create a new column I would call NEW_ID

if ID is unique in table T-->ID
else concatenate(ID,X,Y) using '_' as delimiter

I did have a kind of solution, where I write a subquery to get the count of ID then write and if statement saying if count(ID)=1 then ID, else the concatenated but I am blanking out on to actually implement it in SQL world.

Thanks, I appreciate your help in advance :)

I did have a kind of solution, where I write a subquery to get the count of ID then write and if statement saying if count(ID)=1 then ID, else the concatenated but I am blanking out on to actually implement it in SQL world.

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(ID,X,Y)
from table 
left join ....got stuck here on how to tie it to the next part 

SELECT ID, COUNT(ID)
FROM table 
group by id
having count(ID)<>1 ...or perhaps =1. I need to work with all values anyway
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add to the question some example input and output?

Comment: Have you seen the decode() function?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DECODE_expression.html

Comment: @PaulT. I added a screenshot, can you see it?

Comment: @BillWeiner I didn't know this function before. I am really new to SQL and Redshift. I will look into it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should be straight forward.  On Redshift I like the decode() function for cases like this but a CASE statement works just as well.

```
select id, x, y, 
  decode(id_count, 1, id, id::text || '_' || x || '_' || y) as concat_col
from (
  select id, x, y, count(*) over (partition by id) as id_count
  from <table>
);
```

Comment: wow I don't know how to decode this query but it worked...I guess I'm just going to reverse engineer it. Thank you so very much!